# Log4j exception in grails

Tags: grails, log4j

log.debug("Id:" + domain.id)

being domain.id a long value, I get the exception:

Exception Message: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.debug() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Id:9] Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), dump(), get(java.lang.Object), get(java.lang.Object), get(java.lang.Object), merge(groovy.util.ConfigObject)

Is it required in grails to include only strings parameters in debug's arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `log` is an instance of Log4J's `Logger` class?  The error message looks a lot like it's an instance of a completely different class (`groovy.util.ConfigObject`) instead.

Besides, as you can see from the error message, the methid *is* being called with just a string.  The concatenation of the values (into a single string) has already happened by the time the method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you are using log in a scope where there is no log defined.

Actually i have the same problem since i am trying to log from the config.groovy script.